# What does אֲפִיקוֹמָן mean?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, translation

Although [much](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15425/13811) [has](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/585/13811) [been](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14462/13811) [discussed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56945/13811) here regarding the various customs surrounding the afikoman, none seem to address what the word אֲפִיקוֹמָן means. What is its definition and where does it derive from?

**Note**: [Some](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/881-afikomen) explain אֲפִיקוֹמָן is based on Greek or Aramaic, but don't provide sources to the idea.

Comment: I don't understand. First you say you want its etymology, and then you say not to. Which do you want?

Comment: FWIW the Tiferes Yisrael claims it's Greek, and the Bartenura claims it's Aramaic.

Comment: Thank you for providing sources to the etymology - I certainly am looking for the definition and where it comes from, just not "Greek" without a source saying so. Which mishna in Pesachim are the TY and Bartenura speaking on?

Comment: The one that mentions afikoman... (10:8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jastrow](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38236&st=%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A1&pgnum=120) translates it as:

> 1. to the after meal entertainment
> 2. things belonging to the after-meal
> 3. dessert

[image: Jastrow definition of אפיקומן]

Rashi ([Pesachim 86a s.v. ואמר רב](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37955&st=&pgnum=182)) writes:

> אפיקומן לשון הוציאו כליכם מכאן ונלך ונאכל עוד בחבורה אחרת